# How to safely upgrade CUDA 7.5 to 8.0?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and gtx 780m and cuda 7.5. How can I upgrade to cuda 8.0? Is [this method](https://aichamp.wordpress.com/2016/11/09/updating-nvidia-cuda-to-8-0-x-in-ubuntu-16-04-ec2-gx-instance/) correct?

The nvidia website does not tell me how to upgrade, only install.

What is the easiest and safest way of installing 8.0? elete 7.5 then install 8.0 or upgrade 7.5 to 8.0?

Answer (score 0):

CUDA 8.0 may be unpacked ("installed") into its own directory, without affecting the 7.5 installation.  Change your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the new CUDA 8.0 bin and lib directories, (and remove the CUDA 7.5 additions), test the 8.0 functionality and compatibility, and remove the CUDA 7.5 when you are happy with 8.0

---

My only experience is with the CUDA 8.0 deb, but I assume CUDA 10 would have the same installation options.

Comment: so if i want to use cuda 10.0 then i simply "install" it via https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=runfilelocal then change the mentioned paths ?